# Candidate view for custom keyboard messes up WhatsApp & other app layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a custom keyboard and when I open it, It adjusts the input box fine, but once I start typing and the candidate view pops up, the layout of the application is messed up.

I've included an example of WhatsApp. It doesn't seem to do this with other applications.

Without candidate view:

[image]

With candidate view which messes up the layout and overlays the text a bit:

[image]

My guess is this has something to do with margins/padding, but where should I correct this?

A lot of solutions I've found are for custom text boxes, nothing seems to cover text boxes of other apps.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but may be helpful for someone else. I fixed it by overriding the onComputeInsets:

```
override fun onComputeInsets(outInsets: Insets?) {
    super.onComputeInsets(outInsets)
    if (!isFullscreenMode) {
        outInsets?.contentTopInsets = outInsets?.visibleTopInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: Have worked with custom keyboard I have query

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the overlapping with the input text box by adding a margin to the candidate view. As part of its styling, add android:layout_marginTop and set it to something like 10sp.